# Two Eclipses running on the same machine = ADB race condition

Tags: android, eclipse, google-app-engine, adb, adt

I didn't find information on this annoying problem, and it seem quite common to me, so perhaps I'm missing something obvious.

I'm developing a client server application: AppEngine on one side, Android on the other.
If both workspaces are on the same Eclipse, I find it confusing to debug and develop (same Java perspective..).
So I have two separate installations of Eclipse, one for each.

Both Eclipse *require* a full Google stack each, including ADT.
The problem is that adb is in a race condition, and very often the AppEngine Eclipse wins, and the attached device or emulators appears only on the wrong Eclipse.
I can't debug until I close that Eclipse and restart adb.

1. Is there a way to shut down adb in the AppEngine Eclipse?
2. Is there a *better* way to develop&debug client server, where both are Google stack?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found a workaround:

In the Eclipse instance you want to disable DDMS, select:

```
Windows > Preferences > DDMS
```

And change the "Base local debugger port to some unused port number (such as 22222).

There is an error messages about not being able to connect to DDMS, but after dismissing it, it stops competing with the other Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

In command prompt type

```
cd c:\path to this folders \android-sdk-windows\tools\

adb kill-server
```

It will kill the server

```
adb start-server
```

it will start the server

My Friend ....Hope it will help you

Comment: Thanks, but essentially this is what I do today. If the "wrong" eclipse is still running, it will race again to connect to adb. I'm looking for a better way (if there is one)